# angular typescript ui router doesn't reload page

Tags: javascript, angularjs, typescript, angular-ui-router

I am developing a angular 1.5 app with typescript and ui-router.

Here is my route.ts file

```
export class Route {

  static $inject = ['$location'];

  constructor(private $stateProvider: ng.ui.IStateProvider, private $urlRouterProvider: ng.ui.IUrlRouterProvider, private $locationProvide: ng.ILocationProvider) {
    this.init();
    this.$locationProvide.html5Mode({
        enabled: true,
        requireBase: false
        });
  }

  private init(): void {
    this.$stateProvider.state('/main', Route.defaultState());

    this.$urlRouterProvider.otherwise('/main');
  }

  private static defaultState(): ng.ui.IState {
    return {
        url: "/main", 
        template: "<h1>Hello from Main</h1>"
    }
  }


}

angular.module('app')
.config(($stateProvider: ng.ui.IStateProvider, $urlRouterProvider: ng.ui.IUrlRouterProvider, $locationProvider:ng.ILocationProvider) => {
    return new Route($stateProvider, $urlRouterProvider, $locationProvider)
});
```

and in the module.ts

```
import * as angular from 'angular';
import 'angular-ui-router';

angular.module('app.services', []);
angular.module('app', ['app.services', 'ui.router']);
```

At the first of the load, the app goes to http://localhost:8080/main but if i reload, the app shows "Cannot GET /main"

No exception is thrown. Do you have any idea why this could happen? I don't have any base set in the html.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: This is not an issue on Angular part but on your server part. Your server needs to know that a request on /main is actually served by /. At this point, the setup required is dependent on the web server technology and we need more information to guide you through it. Also, be careful on the `config` part if you plan to minify your code later on.

Comment: I am not making any server call yet. This is static HTML5Mode routing. Please let me know what extra information I should provide.

Comment: Whatever is serving `localhost:8080` knows how to serve `/` but not `/main`. This is why you hitting refresh give you a 404. If you disabled  HTML5 Mode routing, a request to `localhost:8080` will change the path (with the router) to `localhost:8080/#/main` and a refresh will work as the request from a refresh will ask for `localhost:8080/`. You are making a "server" call when accessing the page through a browser.

Comment: Thanks for the comment. But How could I fix the 404 in html5mode other than going back with hash(#)?